# Can someone check this and see if its possible to make smaller and simple

Tags: php, variables, cookies

Below is my code for a currency converter, it sets a new cookie and variable if no cookie exists, check if the cookie has been requested to be changed, and checks the existing cookie and sets a variable for it. I have used a 3rd party variable because on new cookie sets, PHP can't see and therefor read the new cookie until it's been refreshed. Please check if it can be simplified :D

```
/* No Cookie (Default Currency GBP) */
if(!isset($_COOKIE['currency'])) {
    setcookie(currency, GBP, time() + (86400 * 365), "/");
    $currency = "GBP";
    $currencyid = "1";
}

/* Set Varible Based On Exsiting Cookie and Change Varibles */
if (isset($_COOKIE['currency']) == "GBP" ){
    $currency = "GBP";
    $currencyid = "1";
}
elseif (isset($_COOKIE['currency']) == "USD" ){
    $currency = "USD";
    $currencyid = "2";
}

/* Change Cookie and Change Varibles (Because Check Below Wont Find New Varible of Cookie) */
if (isset($_GET['GBP'])) {
    setcookie(currency, GBP, time() + (86400 * 365), "/"); 
    $currency = "GBP";
    $currencyid = "1";
}

elseif (isset($_GET['USD'])) {
    setcookie(currency, USD, time() + (86400 * 365), "/");
    $currency = "USD";
    $currencyid = "2";
}
```

Comment: I believe you have chosen the wrong site. There is another site called [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Is `currency` a constant or did you make a typo and meant `$currency`? If so then the order of your operations is also wrong.

Comment: @Dharman A request for simplification isn't a good request for review, but okay. Should this question be posted on Code Review, user is advised to read [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first and provide the necessary context. What are we looking at, how is it called and why does it exist in the first place.

Comment: Actually I see now, that this code doesn't execute at all....

Comment: `if (isset($_COOKIE['currency']) == "GBP" )` won't ever evaluate to true.

Comment: ok. after review it doesn't work, help

Comment: Try to edit the question and focus on a single problem at a time. What is the use of cookies in this context? Is this a full code or is there more(where the constants come from? are they undefined? typo?) What do you mean by 3rd party variables? Are you displaying PHP errors?

Comment: *"PHP can't see and therefor read the new cookie until it's been refreshed."* - Which is normal. I think you should read the documentation on cookies http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php and then start fresh and keep track by debugging. Remember, cookies only take effect *after* they've been set and contain value. Edit: Not to mention the use of `isset()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have merged two conditions into one expression and ruined the intended logic...

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['currency']) == "GBP" ){
```

Should be:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['currency']) && $_COOKIE['currency'] == "GBP" ){
```

Or some other separated version of that to maintain logic.  As posted, your code is asking if `true|false` == `GBP`.

...Actually, based on your first condition block, the `isset()` is pointless.

Comment: This is too funny. The OP's trying to add their code here https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/21698381

Comment: Yeah, first time I've seen that move.

Comment: Heh, actually I've seen this before :-))

Comment: @Morgan what does your form look like? Do you have fields named `GBP` and `USD`? Or do you have a currency field named `currency`?  This will matter to your last two conditions.  Do you mean to use `GBP` and `USD` and `currency` as constants when setting the cookie data? If not, those strings should be quoted.

Comment: The suggest change worked and its working correctly as planned :D thanks

Comment: @Morganwalton "thanks" is not the way to mark an accepted solution here.  Please award the green tick to my answer if you are satisfied.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/352329